Disabling auto-brightness
I'm running Elementary OS v8.0 on a very old Dell XPS 13 9333 laptop. EOS is a Ubuntu 24.04 LTS variant.
The auto-brightness daemon is constantly popping up, changing the screen brightness. I've turned auto-brightness off in settings and have done the
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power ambient-enabled false

thing, all to no avail.
Is there a solution to this?
Thank you

It seems like you've already taken some of the key steps to disable the auto-brightness feature, but the issue persists. You can try a few additional steps to fully disable the auto-brightness daemon:

Check for any other power management tools:
Sometimes other power management tools might conflict. You can check if there's any other tool like light or xbacklight controlling the brightness:

Run xbacklight -get to check the current brightness level.
If it’s set to change automatically, you might want to turn it off using xbacklight -set <brightness-level> or adjust the configuration of these tools.


Check the logind.conf file:
Another place where auto-brightness might be configured is in the /etc/systemd/logind.conf file. Open it with a text editor (e.g., sudo nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf), and ensure the following lines are set:
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore

After making any changes, reload the systemd configuration with:
sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind


Disable the iio driver (if applicable):
If the system is using an IIO (Industrial I/O) driver for sensor input, the brightness might be affected by this. You can try disabling it:

Find out the exact name of the sensor device by running:
ls /sys/class/leds/

Then, navigate to the relevant sensor directory and disable auto-brightness.


Check gnome-settings-daemon:
Even after disabling it in the settings, sometimes the gnome-settings-daemon might override settings. Try stopping it manually:
killall gnome-settings-daemon

If this works, you could prevent it from starting again by disabling it using:
sudo systemctl disable gnome-settings-daemon


Reinstall the power settings packages:
If none of the above solutions work, you might try reinstalling the power management packages:
sudo apt reinstall gnome-settings-daemon
sudo apt reinstall power-profiles-daemon



Give these a try and see if any of them help resolve the issue!
